# How do I change my resolution in ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu

I just installed uI don't see a display option or screen resolution option in System > Preference.

I'm using ubuntu 10.04 LTS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have System>Preference>Monitors, like in ubuntu 10.10? Or it might be called "Display" like here:
http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-change-screen-resolution-in-ubuntu.html

Comment: Yes, I do, but it doesn't have my resolution, but that's another question. Thanks!